# Postgresql Query Results in Division by 0 After Use of Case to Check for 0

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

The following query is using a subquery to allow for a weighted value to be calculated. The problem I am receiving is a division by 0 error that occurs at random for true 0 value aggregates as well as possible >0 aggregate returns from the subquery.

```
SELECT
  table1.id,
  SUM(subquery1.total_value_1),
  CASE
  WHEN SUM(subquery1.total_value_1) = 0 THEN 0
  ELSE ROUND(SUM(percentage_value * (table1.value_1 /subquery1.total_value_1 ::FLOAT)) ::NUMERIC,2)
  END AS percentage_value
FROM
    table1,
    (SELECT
        id,
        SUM(value_1) AS total_value_1
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE
        report_time BETWEEN '2016-10-28 00:00' AND '2016-10-29 23:59'
    GROUP BY
        id
    ) subquery1
WHERE
  table1.id = subquery1.id
  AND report_time BETWEEN '2016-10-28 00:00' AND '2016-10-29 23:59'
  AND table1.id = 12572
GROUP BY
  table1.id
ORDER BY
  table1.id
```

In some instances, the Case statement is still doing the evaluation of the division despite the value of subquery1.total_value_1 being 0. Just to note, there is no possibility for subquery1.total_value_1 being NULL, as the table defaults this value to 0 on insert if the value added is not defined.

Comment: and yet, if you change `table1.value_1 / subquery1.total_value_1 :: FLOAT` to `table1.value_1 / greatest(0.00000000001, subquery1.total_value_1 :: FLOAT)` - what happens?..

Comment: are you really sure you need the nested select?

Comment: can you show us the schema of table1?

Comment: @VaoTsun That seems to have helped. I am no longer getting the division by 0 error.

Could you explain why that works please?

Comment: well, it means, that `subquery1.total_value_1 :: FLOAT` can be equal to zero, in this case greatest pick up the largest value between zero and `0.00000001`, so you avoid the devision by zero. you have to decide now if you want to divide it by value very close to zero when it is zero or by `1` or take any other decision

Comment: check rows of `SELECT
        id,
        SUM(value_1) AS total_value_1
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE
        report_time BETWEEN '2016-10-28 00:00' AND '2016-10-29 23:59'
    GROUP BY
        id`

Comment: @VaoTsun There are indeed returns of the total_value_1 that equal 0. My question now is why the Case doesn't work when the SUM(total_value_1) = 0. If the SUM() is 0, then I set the result to 0, and the division should not actually occur.

Comment: @MikePearson I create example when sum can be <> 0 while its components can

Answer (score 0):

In example below, sum(column) is 1 for both rows, while column is equal to zero or one:

```
a=# with v as (
  select generate_series(0,1,1) al
) 
select sum(v.al) over(),v.al 
from v;
 sum | al
-----+----
   1 |  0
   1 |  1
(2 rows)
```

so in your `SUM(subquery1.total_value_1) = 0` can be not equal to zero, but `subquery1.total_value_1 ::FLOAT`  will be, this way you get `division by zero`